# How to wait for the result in a single function for all callbacks in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, asynchronous, callback

May be question title not appropriate but I can explain what I want to do in my code

// One  Callback Function

```
  connection_db.query(get_measure_query,function(err,user_data1){
        if(err){
          // throw err;
          let response_data = status_codes.db_error_0001;
          console.log(response_data);
          res.end('error');
        }else {

    }

    });
```

// 2nd  Callback Function

```
  connection_db.query(get_measure_query,function(err,user_data2){
        if(err){
          // throw err;
          let response_data = status_codes.db_error_0001;
          console.log(response_data);
          res.end(enc);
        }else {
      res.end('error');
    }
    });
```

// 3rd Callback Function

```
 connection_db.query(get_measure_query,function(err,user_data3){
        if(err){
          // throw err;
          let response_data = status_codes.db_error_0001;
          console.log(response_data);
          res.end('error');
        }else {

    }
    });
```

Now I need all the data user_data1, user_data2 and user_data3. How can I get this in a single function

```
function allData(){
// This should wait for all the callbacks and then execute

}
```

I hope I am able to understands my question. Please let me know if som eone not understands it well
In advance, thanks for the help guys !

Comment: Use promises! (2 more to go...)

Comment: The only way I can see you doing it is chaining them like `1stCall(function(data1){2ndCall(function(data2))})` or as @undefined has said, change them to promises and then you can make use of [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: what is ```connection_db```? which db library are you using?

Comment: connection_db is a variable in which I maintain my database connection. SQL db

Comment: Will you please implement promise method in the above code ?

Comment: I did it using Promise method. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

```js
// 1. use Promise  Promise.all()
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all


// 2. or gruff
function handleAll(data) {
  if(!handleAll.all) {
    handleAll.all = []
  }
  handleAll.all.push(data)
  if(handleAll.all.length >= 3) {
    //do something with handleAll.all [data1, data2, data3 ..]


    handleAll.all = null
  }
}
// invoke it in all the callback function
connection_db.query(get_measure_query,function(err,user_data1){
  if(err){
    // throw err;
    let response_data = status_codes.db_error_0001;
    console.log(response_data);
    res.end('error');
  }else {
    handleAll(user_data1)
  }
});
```

Comment: Will you please explain with an example

Comment: invoke handleAll in all `1/2/3rd` Callback Function

```
 connection_db.query(get_measure_query,function(err,user_data1){
        if(err){
          // throw err;
          let response_data = status_codes.db_error_0001;
          console.log(response_data);
          res.end('error');
        }else {
        handleAll(user_data1)
    }
    });
...
```

Comment: Now I did it my using Promise method. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it roughly but you can use callback to get all the data in `allData` function. I think the below should work for you without adapting to newer version of code.

```js
 function runALL(allData) {
     connection_db.query(get_measure_query, function(err, user_data1) {
         if (err) {
             // throw err;
             let response_data = status_codes.db_error_0001;
             console.log(response_data);
             res.end('error');
         }
         else {
             connection_db.query(get_measure_query, function(err, user_data2) {
                 if (err) {
                     // throw err;
                     let response_data = status_codes.db_error_0001;
                     console.log(response_data);
                     res.end(enc);
                 }
                 else {
                     connection_db.query(get_measure_query, function(err, user_data3) {
                         if (err) {
                             // throw err;
                             let response_data = status_codes.db_error_0001;
                             console.log(response_data);
                             res.end('error');
                         }
                         else {
                             allData(user_data1, user_data2, user_data3)
                         }
                     });
                 }
             });
         }

     });
 }
 
 function allData((user_data1, user_data2, user_data3) {
     // use user_data1, user_data2, user_data3
 })
 
 runAll(allData)
```

Comment: But this can lead to callback hell. I want to avoid that

Comment: If you don't have many asynch functions(or not going to add in future) then I guess its fine. But if you are not comfortable using callbacks then I will suggest using promises which is much cleaner than callback. This link is helpful I guess,
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises